# Why did Fran say "You did this"?

Tags: plot-explanation, knives-out

In *Knives Out*, when dying, why did Fran say "you did this" to Marta when she knew who the killer was?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Because of her accent "you did this" is almost indistinguishable from "Hugh did this".

She said this because in one of the first scenes in the movie it is explained that Ransom's real name is Hugh but it is only "the help" that call him Hugh, so that is name that Fran used.  This explanation is also recapped at the denouement.

Comment: And the audience is reminded of this plot point when Ransom is brought into the room; the detective refers to him as "Mr. Hugh Ransom Drysdale".